# cakePHP paginator not passing passedargs

Tags: cakephp, components, paginator

I am using cakePHP and I am trying to get the paginator component to pass the get variables, or passedargs, when you click through to different pages. I have a variety of different search input selectors which "filters" the results returned. This works on first view, but the moment I click on a different page, it shows all of the results.

I have the following setup for my paginator:

```
// In my controller class:
public $paginate = array('maxLimit' => 10, 'paramType' => 'querystring');

// Within my action method:
$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array(...),
                        order => array('Model.field ASC'),
                        'limit' => 20 
 );

 // Calling the paginator:
 $results = $this->paginate('Model');
 $this->set(compact('results'));
```

In my view file:

```
 <div class="paging">
<?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
?>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
From my understanding it's better to use the passedArgs, but I am a little unsure as to how to do this. My $this->passedArgs returns no results, so I am creating the passed parameters within my controller example. I also changed my form from Get to Post:

```
 $this->passedArgs["searchfield"] = $_POST["value"];
```

It passes the passedArgs now correctly in the pagination strip, but I am unsure as to how to build the paging conditions array now. In most cases users will not select default values example, one of the filters is date from and date to, and then a search input box, if I leave the dates it will still created the argumens and not return any results so in essence my url would be something like:

```
 http://localhost/site/controller/action/page:3/datefrom:0/dateto:0/searchFor:survey
```

Any assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass by all parameters in the view with:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
```

or assign the params manually:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => array("0", "1")));
```

befor echoing the paginator

See the [CakePHP Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Pagination.html#pagination-in-views) for further Examples

Comment: Hi @Nebel54, thank you for your suggestion. I think I found the problem, and that is that my filter form, or search form, is only posting the values to GET so my $this->passedArgs is empty. Can you perhaps indicate how I built the passedArgs?

Comment: Can you post how your get parameters look like? are they built like /param1:true/param2:name or like /?param1=true&param2=name

Comment: it's /param1:value/param2:value, but now because not all parameters will always have values, it will do param1:0/param2:possiblevalue/ which will break the query

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cleanest solution, but I would unset the default values you don't need in your condition array e.g. if ($my_passed_args['datefrom']==0) { unset($my_passed_args['datefrom']); before assigning the conditions in your action method